# Time-stamping Different Processes

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I am looking to create a `.txt` file at the end of my script that will inform the user when each process is run, it main function is to determine how long each step of the process takes to run. In the interest of space I have eliminated the different steps of the script, they are just gdal tools. Thanks in advance.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


sttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('(Time_Run = %Y-%d-%m_%H:%M:%S)')



def timeStamped (fname, fmt='{fname}_%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S .txt'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)
with open(timeStamped('Files_Used_In_Sigma_Test'),'w') as outf:
    outf.write("###" + sttime + "####")
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write("#######################################")
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write("SIGMA TEST -- UTILIS ISRAEL LTD.")
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write("#######################################")
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write(src_dataset.fileName + sttime)
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write(srcVH.fileName + sttime)
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.write(str(stDev) + sttime)
    outf.write(" \n")
    outf.close()
```

Comment: Could you explain what you question is?

Comment: Of course. I am looking to produce a text file that produces something like this...

`###(Time_Run = 2016-13-11_20:17:42)#### 
SIGMA TEST -- UTILIS ISRAEL LTD. 

C:/Users/jack.UTILIS/Desktop/Components/Polarization_Images/IMG-HV-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img(Time_Run = 2016-13-11_20:17:42) 
C:/Users/jack.UTILIS/Desktop/Components/Polarization_Images/IMG-VH-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img(Time_Run = 2016-13-11_20:17:42)`

However as you can see, the same timestamp is applied to each line. My ultimate goal is to timestamp the completion of each gdal process.